# Check for "no documents" state or empty data-set in FirebaseUI's FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebaseui

I wrote a custom FirebaseRecylerAdapter, based on FirebaseUI [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) like this:

```
class FavoritesAdapter(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Favorite, FavoritesAdapter.FavoritesHolder>(buildOptions(lifecycleOwner)) {

companion object {
    private fun buildQuery() = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .reference
            .child("favorites")
            .limitToLast(50)

    private fun buildOptions(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Favorite>()
            .setQuery(buildQuery(), Favorite::class.java)
            .setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner)
            .build()
}

//...
```

This class overrides an onDataChanged() function:

```
override fun onDataChanged() {
    // Called each time there is a new data snapshot. You may want to use this method
    // to hide a loading spinner or check for the "no documents" state and update your UI.
    // ...

}
```

Now, how do I actually check for that "no documents" state in order to update my UI? I can find no way to check for an empty data-set. I am looking for something like getItemCount().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapter does have an `itemCount` property and you can also use `snapshots` to get a live list of your model objects. Example:

```
override fun onDataChanged() {
    if (itemCount == 0) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Both the methods I mentioned can be used in `onDataChanged()`. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: `you can also use snapshots to get a live list of your model objects`  Could you please give an example in your answer, too?